# How to make `mktime` format with milliseconds?

Tags: php, date, ffmpeg, milliseconds, mktime

I need make 24 frames per second with PHP `ffmpeg`. This is current format of

```
$t = mktime(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 98);
```

Later I use this function

```
exec("/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -ss " . date("H:i:s", $t) . " -i {$file} -f mjpeg -vframes 1 -s {$size} {$tmpfile}");
```

In `date("H:i:s", $t)` I need make `date("H:i:s.milliseconds", $t)`. This is not working `date("H:i:s.u", $t)` because of `mktime` format (hours, minutes, seconds, day. month, years) I guess.

So, is it possible to add milliseconds to `mktime`?

Comment: Use `microtime()`

Comment: But I need something like this ` $t = mktime(0, 0, 0,$microtime_variable, 1, 1, 98);`

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest solution to print a user defined "H:i:s.u" time is using [DateTime::setTime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.settime.php) with [DateTime::format](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php), which supports microsecond:

```php
echo (new DateTime())->setTime(1, 2, 3, 456789)->format('H:i:s.u');
```

Result:

```
01:02:03.456789
```

That means your PHP can be written as such:

```php
<?php

$hour = 1; $minute = 1; $second = 98;
$millisecond = 123; // or whatever
$t = (new DateTime())->setTime($hour, $minute, $second, $millisecond * 1000);

exec("/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -ss {$t->format('H:i:s.v')} -i {$file} -f mjpeg -vframes 1 -s {$size} {$tmpfile}");
```